# How do I configure kendo.data.DataSource to use Function for read?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to configure a kendo.data.DataSource in my viewModel to return a simple json object through a function. I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
departmentDropDownDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource( {

read: function () {
      return {
      data: [
                  { Department: "Electronics" },
                  { Department: "Facilities" },
                  { Department: "Project Support" },
                  { Department: "Services" }   ]
       };
    }
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` accepts an argument, call it `op` and then invoke `op.success` with the data as argument.

```
read : function (op) {
    op.success([
              { Department: "Electronics" },
              { Department: "Facilities" },
              { Department: "Project Support" },
              { Department: "Services" }   ] );
}
```